# use implode and ajax to insert checkbox values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

i want to insert my checkbox values, i dont know how to take all the values using ajax and use implode to insert them in one row.

```js
// this is my javascript where i take the data ,

function saveData() {
  var modsubj = $('#modalsubject').val();
  var modsect = $('#modalsection').val();
  var modday = $('#modalday').val();
  var modstart = $('#modalstarttime').val();
  var modend = $('#modalendtime').val();
  var moduser = $('#userID').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "modal.funcs.php?p=add",
    data: "subj=" + modsubj + "&sect=" + modsect + "&day=" + modday + "&start=" + modstart + "&end=" + modend + "&user=" + moduser
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="modalday[]" name="modalday[]" value="M">Monday &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="modalday[]" name="modalday[]" value="T">Tuesday &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="modalday[]" name="modalday[]" value="W">Wednesday &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="modalday[]" name="modalday[]" value="Th">Thursday &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="modalday[]" name="modalday[]" value="F">Friday &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
```

this is my php function, i used the implode function so that i can insert the data on one row.

```
$page = isset($_GET['p'])?$_GET['p']:'';
  if($page=='add'){
      foreach ($_POST['day'] as $key => $value) {
        $subj = $_POST['subj'];
        $sect = $_POST['sect']; 
        $day = implode("",$_POST['day']); 
        $strTime = $_POST['start'];
        $endTime = $_POST['end'];
        $user_id = $_POST['user'];
      }

        $auth_user->createSchedule($subj,$sect,$day,$strTime,$endTime,$user_id);
        $schedRow = $auth_user->readSchedule();

  } else if ($page=='edit') {

  }
```

Comment: IDs must be unique so var modday = $('#modalday').val(); will not work. Change id to  class="modalday" and loop over the array returned  from `$(".modalday :checked")`

Comment: noted, then how can i use this to take all the data and compress it with implode?

Comment: See the modification to my comment. What is the expected output? You can return "M,T,Th,F" to the PHP for example

Comment: i followed your instructions specifically but its still the same, are you sure i can do it this way? im not really confident of my code, i was expecting some drastic changes but it would be great if this will do, i think im still missing something though

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to send a list to the server

You can explode the day to get an array of days

To add more items, add a comma and more key values:

```
 data: { day: modday.join(","),
         subj:$('#modalsubject').val() // no comma on the last
       }
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#save").on("click", function() {
    saveData();
  });
});

function saveData() {
  var modday = [];
  $('.modalday:checked').each(function() {
    modday.push(this.value);
  });
  console.log(modday);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "modal.funcs.php?p=add",
    data: { day: modday.join(",") }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="modalday" name="modalday[]" value="M">Monday &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="modalday" name="modalday[]" value="T">Tuesday &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="modalday" name="modalday[]" value="W">Wednesday &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="modalday" name="modalday[]" value="Th">Thursday &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="modalday" name="modalday[]" value="F">Friday &nbsp;&nbsp;
  </label>
</div>
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

Comment: But he needs key value pair, so that he can pull values against key in PHP

Comment: Now he does not need to implode anything. The checkboxes are arriving already imploded

Comment: Right. How does he perform POST action on values without keys. albert,enistin will send as a value but how does application know, which is first and last name. It would be nice if it goes, firstName=albert&lastName=eistin

Comment: I don't get your comment. If he adds `, "user": + $('#userID').val()` to my code he will get the $_POST["user"] in the php - he only currently implodes the checkboxes

Comment: the name-value pair would currently be `modalday[]=T,modalday[]=W,modalday[]=F` if he did not pre-process them.  The idea of [] is to deliver an array to the server but since he is using AJAX and wants to implode, where is the usecase for a name-value?

Comment: modday.push(this.value) and modday.join(",") will produce "day:M,T,W". Now suppose if I only need W as value in PHP, how do I extract?

Comment: It is not your code. If he needs just wed, he will need to code it differently with or without my suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I tried this myself, and I think most of the action can occur in your saveData function, not in PHP.

I'm assuming you will change your ids to a class instead, as id's should be unique:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="modalday" name="modalday[]" value="M">Monday &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Check this out:

```
function saveData() {
  var modsubj = $('#modalsubject').val();
  var modsect = $('#modalsection').val();

  var moddayAll = document.getElementsByClassName('modalday');

  var modday = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < moddayAll.length; i++) {
    if (moddayAll[i].checked) {
      modday.push(moddayAll[i].value);
    }
  }

  var modstart = $('#modalstarttime').val();
  var modend = $('#modalendtime').val();
  var moduser = $('#userID').val();

  var add = 'add';

  $.post("modal.funcs.php", {p:add, subj:modsubj, sect:modsect, day:modday.join(","), start:modstart, end:modend, user:moduser},
    function( data ) {
      // do whatever you want with data returned from modal.funcs.php
    }
  );

};
```

I just used vanilla JavaScript to select all the modalday elements, then loop through them and add the values (M, T, W, etc...) of the ones that are checked to the modday array:

```
  var moddayAll = document.getElementsByClassName('modalday');

  var modday = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < moddayAll.length; i++) {
    if (moddayAll[i].checked) {
      modday.push(moddayAll[i].value);
    }
  }
```

Then, since you are using the POST method anyway, I used JQuery's .post(), and passed the 'p' param along with the data, instead of in a query string. You'll notice this is where the modday array is turned to a string with the join() call as well:

```
  var add = 'add';

  $.post("modal.funcs.php", {p:add, subj:modsubj, sect:modsect, day:modday.join(","), start:modstart, end:modend, user:moduser},
    function( data ) {
      // do whatever you want with data returned from modal.funcs.php
    }
  );
```

Then, in modal.funcs.php, you can just get the values from the $_REQUEST variable and pass them to your functions:

```
<?php

$page = $_REQUEST['p'];

if ($page == 'add') {

  $subj = $_REQUEST['subj'];
  $sect = $_REQUEST['sect']; 
  $day = $_REQUEST['day']; 
  $strTime = $_REQUEST['start'];
  $endTime = $_REQUEST['end'];
  $user_id = $_REQUEST['user'];

  $auth_user->createSchedule($subj,$sect,$day,$strTime,$endTime,$user_id);
  $schedRow = $auth_user->readSchedule();

} else if ($page=='edit') {

}
```

$_REQUEST['day] will be a comma-separated string of the values of the checkboxes that were checked. If you need to do further processing of the array here, you can add another step to do so.